# Redux state getting reset after page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using Redux with React and I have a list of items on the first Component which is then stored on to the Redux store and when I go to another page the store is reset.

**Reducer**

```
const postsreducer=(state=['hello','world'],action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'GET_LIST':
            return state
        case 'COPY':
            state=action.payload
            return state
        default:
            return state

    }
};

export default postsreducer
```

/////copy data to store

```
axios.get('http://my-json-server.typicode.com/VKR981/demo/posts/').then(res=>{  dispatch1(copyposts(res.data)); })
```

/////goto another component

```
<Button href='/createpost'>Create post</Button>
```

state is back to 'hello world'

Comment: Are you sure that the store was set inter first place? Check the Redux browser extension.

Comment: what is the Button component doing ? Are you just doing browser routing or going to a whole new page ? If the latter, it would reset the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, do your switch like this:

```
switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_LIST':
        return state;
    case 'COPY':
        return action.payload;
    default:
        return state;
}
```

then, use react router's `Link` for route changes like this:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Button as={Link} to="/createpost">Create post</Button>
```